# OnClick event does not fire on HTML button when clicked on the content of the button

Tags: button, onclick

The onClick event of my HTML button only fires when I click on the button itself, and not if I click on the text or the image inside the button - i.e. if clicked for example on the lower grey part of the button the event will fire, if clicked on the text 'Legenda', the event will not fire.

How do I fire this event by also clicking on the text or the image inside the button?

HTML:

```
<button onclick="dropdown()" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all dropbtn"><img class="legendaicon" src="images/legend-01.png"><span style="vertical-align:super">Legenda</span></button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#legenda {
right: 0.5%;
margin-top: 0.5%;
z-index: 2000;
position: absolute;

}

.legendaicon {
    height: 25px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    float: right;
}

.dropdown-content p {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    right: 0;
}

.show {
    display: block;
}
```

JS:

```
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function dropdown() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See the code in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69u5vxb5/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you clicking the text or image inside the button, you actually calling the js function inside `window.onclick` which will remove the class of `div`. You can add an ID for the button and add an event listener

```js
function dropdown() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show", true);
}

window.addEventListener('click', function(e){   
  if (!document.getElementById('btnID').contains(e.target)){
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
               openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#legenda {
right: 0.5%;
margin-top: 0.5%;
z-index: 2000;
position: absolute;

}

.legendaicon {
    height: 25px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    float: right;
}

.dropdown-content p {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    right: 0;
}

.show {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<button id="btnID" onclick="dropdown()" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all dropbtn"><img class="legendaicon" src="images/legend-01.png"><span style="vertical-align:super">Legenda</span></button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the easy fix!